# Embedded Visual Force Gauge Chart

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-charting, graph

I have been tasked with making a gauge chart that will be embedded in our customer 'location' object that will be unique to each location, based on 3 key metrics within the location.  I know *what* they want, I'm just not sure where to start.  I have very little experience with apex/visual force, so I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction!

I have been looking at this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/10/animated-visualforce-charts.html and it seems to have some good material on making a gauge chart in VF.  However I'm not sure how I would get the data that I need to  display at the level it should.

I need to make a formula which adds the average length of time that the cases in the site have been open (Case Open Length__c AVG), whether or not the customer is down, or has been down in the last 7 days (Customer_Down__c TRUE/FALSE) and how many cases the site currently has open.  I then need to make the resulting number a percentage, and plop it into the Gauge chart so that employees can see at a glance how 'healthy' the site is.

Sorry if that does not make sense, please let me know if anyone has any suggestions or comments,

Thank you!